# xpath selecting node with condition

Tags: xpath, scrapy

Please am using Scrapy a python based framework to scrape a site but I can't figure out how to select text with the class `value ellipsis ph`. Sometimes with the class there is a strong tag. So far I have succeeded in extracting text without the child tag of `strong` .

```
<div class="right">
    <div class="attrs">
        <div class="attr">
            <span class="name">Main Products:</span>
                <div class="value ellipsis ph">
 // Here below i needed to select it ignoring the strong tag
                    <strong>Shoes</strong> 
                    (Sport
                    <strong>Shoes</strong>
                    ,Casual
                    <strong>Shoes</strong>
                    ,Hiking
                    <strong>Shoes</strong>
                    ,Skate
                    <strong>Shoes</strong>
                    ,Football
                    <strong>Shoes</strong>
                    )
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<div class="right">
    <div class="attrs">
        <div class="attr">
            <span class="name">Main Products:</span>
                <div class="value ellipsis ph">
                    Cap, Shoe, Bag // could select this

                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

From the root of selected node here is what works. to select just the text without strong tag.

```
"/div[@class='right']/div[@class='attrs']/div[@class='attr']/div/text()").extract()
```

Comment: `//div[@class="value ellipsis ph"]/text()` or your xpath - both take text only without `<span>`

Comment: that works for the line where "Cap, Shoe, Bag // could select this" what about that with <strong> I needed to select text in and outside the strong tag too

Comment: http://www.utilities-online.info/xpath/?save=7e75c83d-ef45-491d-a4c5-7f3d868b00d3-xpath

Comment: Tried this: `//div[@class="value ellipsis ph"]//text()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the text representation of the `div` elements with class `value ellipsis ph`, you can:

- either select all descendant text nodes, and not only children, using `.//text()`
- or make use of XPath's string functions on the `div` element

Here are 2 options in action:

```
>>> selector = scrapy.Selector(text="""<div class="right">
...     <div class="attrs">
...         <div class="attr">
...             <span class="name">Main Products:</span>
...                 <div class="value ellipsis ph">
...  <!-- // Here below i needed to select it ignoring the strong tag -->
...                     <strong>Shoes</strong> 
...                     (Sport
...                     <strong>Shoes</strong>
...                     ,Casual
...                     <strong>Shoes</strong>
...                     ,Hiking
...                     <strong>Shoes</strong>
...                     ,Skate
...                     <strong>Shoes</strong>
...                     ,Football
...                     <strong>Shoes</strong>
...                     )
...                 </div>
...         </div>
...     </div>
... </div>
... 
... 
... <div class="right">
...     <div class="attrs">
...         <div class="attr">
...             <span class="name">Main Products:</span>
...                 <div class="value ellipsis ph">
...                     Cap, Shoe, Bag <!-- // could select this -->
... 
...                 </div>
...         </div>
...     </div>
... </div>""")
>>> for div in selector.css('div.value.ellipsis.ph'):
...     print "---"
...     print "".join(div.xpath('.//text()').extract())
... 
---


                    Shoes 
                    (Sport
                    Shoes
                    ,Casual
                    Shoes
                    ,Hiking
                    Shoes
                    ,Skate
                    Shoes
                    ,Football
                    Shoes
                    )

---

                    Cap, Shoe, Bag 


>>> for div in selector.css('div.value.ellipsis.ph'):
...     print "---"
...     print div.xpath('string()').extract_first()
... 
---


                    Shoes 
                    (Sport
                    Shoes
                    ,Casual
                    Shoes
                    ,Hiking
                    Shoes
                    ,Skate
                    Shoes
                    ,Football
                    Shoes
                    )

---

                    Cap, Shoe, Bag 


>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

As @splash58 writes in the comment the

```
//div[@class="value ellipsis ph"]//text()
```

XPath gets both text contents. Naturally in the first part it is a list of texts -- however they include the text in the `<strong>` tags and outside of them. Because `text()` gets all text content inside of a subtree -- even if there are more child-tags available.

Comment: You need to add a second "/" just before `text()`. A single slash will only grab the `text()` nodes that are direct children of the previous `div`, not the `text()` nodes that are children of the `<strong>` elements. The double slash means to traverse all children.